# Android: SVG Drawables Stop Working or Glitch in RecyclerView Lists

Tags: android, svg, android-recyclerview, drawable, android-glide

I am having an issue where I imported some SVG drawables (that are optimised in Illustrator and have short path data - so their complexity is out of discussion) and displayed them in RecyclerView items. The problem is that, after testing the application many times, they stop working or they start rendering with glitches (like missing chunks or shapes). Weirdly enough, an app cache wipe resolves the issue and they work normally until after I ran the app from Android Studio about 5-6 times.

Here is what I mean by 'stopped working' : [image]

[image]

In one activity they appear as red warnings, in another one they appear as a fingerprint icon (tho I do not have such an icon in the entire project, nor fingerprint implementation).

Here is the implementation:

I add the entries in room database like this:

```
Category(icon = R.drawable.ic_category_homepage)
```

where a category data class looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
  val title: String,
  @DrawableRes
  val icon: Int
)
```

So I add the SVG drawable reference as a DrawableRes Int in the local storage. Then, when I'm displaying the icon in the adapter, I use Glide:

```
        Glide.with(context)
          .load(category.icon)
          .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
          .into(itemView.categoryIV)
```

Here is the entire adapter:

```
class DrawerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val categories: ArrayList<Category> = ArrayList()

fun submitCategories(newFeed: List<Category>, lifecycleCoroutineScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope) {
    lifecycleCoroutineScope.launch {
        val result = coroutineRunOnComputationThread {
            val oldFeed = categories
            val result: DiffUtil.DiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                DrawerDiffCallback(oldFeed, newFeed)
            )
            categories.clear()
            categories.addAll(newFeed)
            result
        }
        coroutineRunOnMainThread {
            result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@DrawerAdapter)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = categories.size
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return if (categories.isNullOrEmpty()) 0 else categories[position].id
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return DrawerItemViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_drawer_menu))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) =
    (holder as DrawerItemViewHolder).bind(categories[position])

inner class DrawerItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(category: Category) = with(itemView) {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(category.icon)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(itemDrawerIVIcon)

        if (category.preConfigured && category.resTitle != null)
            itemDrawerTVTitle.text = context.resources.getString(category.resTitle)
        else
            itemDrawerTVTitle.text = category.title
    }
}

private inner class DrawerDiffCallback(
    private var oldFeed: List<Category>,
    private var newFeed: List<Category>
) : DiffUtil.Callback() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldItem = oldFeed[oldItemPosition]
        val newItem = newFeed[newItemPosition]
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldItem = oldFeed[oldItemPosition]
        val newItem = newFeed[newItemPosition]
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldFeed.size
    override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newFeed.size
}
```

}

Any idea why I get this weird behavior?

Comment: Please Update your question with recycler view adapter.

Comment: @Nikhil I have.

Comment: Can you remove this line "transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())" and confirm that the glitiching issue still exisit or not

Comment: @Nikhil same behavior

Comment: So the correct icon is the up/down arrows?  The exclamation and the fingerprint are errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve your glitching issue.

```
Picasso.get().load(category.icon)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder_round)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_round)
            .resize(100, 100)
            .into(itemDrawerIVIcon)
```

Just replace your Glide with Picasso with above config